# Alternating CSS classes for dynamic content

Tags: theme-development, css, automation

This is for a gallery that's populated automatically, images are pulled in from child pages. Layout is: 2 images in a row and they must be left- and right-aligned respectively.

I can't figure out a way to add a space between them.

- When I add margin or padding, the 2nd image gets pushed off to the next line;
- Without margin, they're side by side (and only the left one is properly aligned).

So I figured alternating CSS classes might work, but not sure how to make the odd images float left, and even images - float right. And the odd/even class for the images will change based on the number of child posts (and therefore, the number of images imported into this Gallery page).

```
<div id="gallery-container">
    <?php
    $mypages = get_pages( array( 'child_of' => $post->ID, 'sort_column' => 'post_date', 'sort_order' => 'desc' ) );

    foreach( $mypages as $page ) {
    $content = $page->post_content;
    if ( ! $content ) // Check for empty page
    continue;

    $content = apply_filters( 'the_content', $content );
?>


        <div class="gallery-preview">
            <div id="zoom">
                <?php echo $content; ?>
                <h3><a href="http://mettedesigns.com/gallery/<?php echo $page->post_title; ?>"><?php echo $page->post_title; ?></a></h3>
            </div>
        </div>


<?php
}   
?>  
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Close-voted as **off-topic**. This is a **PHP/CSS** question, *not* a **WordPress** question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use PHP modulo operator (%) to determine the classes and use CSS to float them all left and set clear:right to the odd class.

Kind of hard to picture how you're pulling the images without the code though.  Could you post a clip of the code you used to pull the images?

If not you can resort to JS to add the classes dynamically after the page loads *shudder*.

Comment: Please see the revised original. That's pretty much it for the gallery page.

Comment: I'll probably have to make the images into <li>, that's fine. But I don't know enough PHP to write my own anything, get by with revising other people's code for now. Thanks!

Comment: Um firstly. I don't know why you're putting images into a post's content and putlling child posts/pages, that doesn't make any sense?  WordPress has a "gallery" option in posts when you upload images via the media uploader in the post page, it gives you the option to embed all the images into a gallery which WP automatically generates.  There's no need to for your code.  So long as you are using the latest version of WordPress.

Comment: Wordpress will generate the css class columns when it loads the gallery, you can choose many options.. just check out http://codex.wordpress.org/Gallery_Shortcode

Comment: Each image in the gallery is linked to the Child page from which the image is pulled. When a child page is added, image from `the_content` is automatically added to the Parent page. So you see, it's not a regular gallery I need, but a grid of preview images based on the Child pages.

Yes, it can all be done manually, but I'm trying to simplify the maintenance for the person who will be updating the site in the future.

Comment: In that case.. it's still better to grab an array of the child pages via the WP_Query, then ittereate through each page and look to see if that page has any images attached, instead of pulling the content as well.. If for some reason the client adds text content to the child pages that will also be displayed.

Comment: Thank you, I had a total DUH moment there. I've used a featured page plugin many times in the past, no idea why I didn't think of that this time!!

Comment: I was actually thinking this would be simpler:  https://gist.github.com/3261304  I haven't fully tested the code, but that should go in the page template for the page you want to use as a featured page.   It gets the current page's children, then echos out each child's image attachments, also using the modulo to add an even/odd class to the image so you can style it.  Let me know if you use it and it works.  ;)  Just remember to modify the thumbnial size to the size you want to use.

Comment: Thank you for this! It got the Child page titles but no images, and I did replace `thumbnail` with `gallery`. Tried other sizes as well (`post-thumbnail` and `large`) but no luck. Rrrreally good news: page titles have the odd and even classes! :D

Comment: Here's the output `<img class="even" alt="Gravel stone" src="Array">`

Comment: I ended up using this:
 - in the gallery page http://pastebin.com/jsbb05Ns 
 - in the header, added this http://pastebin.com/Tsyg3D7C